# Sharing Python multiprocessing shared Value with C extension

Tags: python, c, python-multiprocessing, share, c-api

I have two processes in python that share a single boolean flag:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

class MyProcess(Process):
   def __init__(self):
       self.flag = Value('B',false)
       # [...]

   def run(self):
       while self.active:
           # do_something()
           if some_condition:
               self.work_to_be_extended__()


   def work_to_be_extended__(self) -> bool:
       while some_internal_loop_condition:
           if self.flag.value:
               # do something
      return result
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_proc = MyProcess()
    my_proc_flag = my_proc.flag
    my_proc.start()
    # [...] Some work
    if condition:
        my_proc_flag.value = True
```

I need to put `MyProcess.work_to_be_extended` in an extension module to be executed in C code. Something like:

```
bool extended_work(void):
{
    while (some_condition) {
        if (my_proc_flag) {
            do_something()
        }
    return result
}
```

I've not designed the extension yet, since I'd need to understand first how to share the `MyProcess.flag` variable. Please, **note that I don't need to *pass* the variable value, I need to *pass its reference* in order for the extension to see a change in the flag value operated in the main process where the extension does not live`.**

Hope I've been quite clear**

Answer (score 1):

Multiprocessing has a sharedctypes submodule for ctypes array and values. You can use it to create a shared ctypes (a int in my example). And then use ctypes.byref to send a pointer to that int.
Since the underlying mechanism is SHM (not some hidden piping under the hood), the pointed memory by this reference is really the same in both process. `shval.value` is `*p` pointed by the `p` argument passed, that is `byref(shval)`.

So, no need for the size 1 array of my previous answer, and, more importantly, for the disclaimer accompanying it.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void myf(volatile uint32_t *p){
    for(;;){
        printf("<c>%d</c>\n", *p);
        if(*p==100) return;
        (*p)++;
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import multiprocessing.sharedctypes as st
import ctypes

mylib=ctypes.CDLL("libtoto.so")
mylib.myf.argtypes=[ctypes.c_void_p]
shval=st.RawValue(st.ctypes.c_uint32,12)

class MyProcess(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        mylib.myf(st.ctypes.byref(shval))

if __name__=="__main__":
    myproc=MyProcess()
    myproc.start()
    while True:
        i=int(input("val>"))
        shval.value=i
```

So, short answer to your question is: use `multiprocessing.sharedctypes` and pass `byref(sharedval)` to your function.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I took much time to comment and upvote just because I needed to extend your advice to other interface solution such as C-API and Boost::Python. The solution I've proposed couldn't be there without this answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Premise

This answer comes from an adaptation of the good solution given by @chrslg. This extends that usage to apply to other paradigm of Python/C programming, such as C Extension API, Cython and Boost::Python.

Please, read that answer first for a deeper background.

### Overview and core summary:

Using a `sharedctypes.RawValue` as the required variable, it is possible to access the underlying data address by means of the method [`sharedctypes.ctypes.addressof`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.addressof).

Therefore, one can pass the address of the variable as a `long long int` (64 bit) and cast it into a pointer to the required data. For example, for a `uint8_t` variable, one has into the C extension

```
 int64_t address; // This is initialized in some way, depending on the C interface to python
 
 // Pointer to shared data
 uint8_t* pointer = (uint8_t*)(address);

 printf("Current value of shared data: %u\n", pointer);
```

## Working example for different Python - C/C++ interfaces

### Common C shared library

Let's create a base, simple C library that just read for 1 time per second the value of the variable being shared:

```
// cshare_data/cshare_data.c

#include "cshare_data.h"

#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void cshare_data(uint8_t* data, char from_where_called) {
    char *s = NULL;
    if (from_where_called == 0) {
        s = "cTypes CDLL";
    } else if (from_where_called == 1)
    {
        s = "Python C Extension";
    } else if (from_where_called == 2)
    {
        s = "Boost::Python";
    } else if (from_where_called == 3)
    {
        s = "Cython";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("C code read from %s a value of: %u\n", s, *data);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

The header:

```
// cshare_data/cshare_data.h

#ifndef CSHARE_DATA_H
#define CSHARE_DATA_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

extern void cshare_data(uint8_t*, char);

#endif
```

### Python shared data editing process

For the rest of the examples, I'll refer to the following Python process that is modifying the shared data (`unsigned char` in the example):

```
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import RawValue, Value
import multiprocessing.sharedctypes as st
from multiprocessing import Process


class MyProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.int_val = RawValue(st.ctypes.c_ubyte, 0)
    def run(self) -> None:
        import time
        for _ in range(10):
            print('Value in Python Process: ', self.int_val.value)
            self.int_val.value += 1
            time.sleep(1)

my_proc = MyProcess()
my_proc.start()
```

**NOTE: This will not be repeated hereinafter.**

#### Python C Extension

A Python C Extension API that makes use of the above pattern follows:

```
#include <Python.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "cshare_data.h"

static PyObject *cshare_data_wrapper(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *val = NULL;

    // This will store the address of the uchar variable being passed from Python
    int64_t address = 0;

    // Convert the single element tuple into a 8-byte int (address)
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "L", &address)) {
        printf("Error parsing Tuple\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Now address is reinterpreted as the shared variable pointer
    uint8_t *pointer = (uint8_t *)(address);
    
    // Call the library function
    cshare_data(pointer, 1);

    return Py_None;
}

static PyMethodDef CShapreDataMethods[] = {
    {"cshare_data", cshare_data_wrapper, METH_VARARGS, "Python interface for sharedata C library function"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef cshareddata_module = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "csharedata_module",
    "Python interface for the fputs C library function",
    -1,
    CShapreDataMethods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_cshare_data_pyext(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&cshareddata_module);
}
```

Please, refer to [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) and this very good [tutorial](https://realpython.com/build-python-c-extension-module/#writing-a-python-interface-in-c) for deeper insight about Python C-API

### Boost::Python

Very similar to what done for the Python C-API, the `boost` wrapper looks like:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "cshare_data.h"
}
#include <boost/python.hpp>

void cshare_data_boost_wrapper(long long int data_address) {
    uint8_t* data = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(data_address);
    cshare_data(data, 2);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(ctrigger) {
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("cshare_data", cshare_data_boost_wrapper);
}
```

### CMake - Library buildings

Moving from a project with the following tree structure:

````
```
project_root
|   cshare_data.py
|---clibs
|   |   cshare_data_boost.so
|   |   cshare_data_pyext.so
|   |   cshare_data.so
|
|---cshare_data
|   |   cshare_data.c
|   |   cshare_data.h
|   
|   CMakeList.txt
```
````

The following compilation CMake script was used:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

project (cshare_data)

set(CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_PREFIX "")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX "")

# Common C shared library

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/clibs)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cshare_data)
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/clibs)
# --- Common C shared library ---
add_library(cshare_data SHARED cshare_data/cshare_data.c)

# Needed for Python C Extension Module and Boost::Python
include_directories("/usr/include/python3.8")

# --- Python C Extension Module library ---
add_library(cshare_data_pyext MODULE cshare_data_pyinterface/cshare_data_pyext.c)
target_link_libraries(cshare_data_pyext python3.8)
target_link_libraries(cshare_data_pyext cshare_data)


# --- Python C Extension Module library ---
include_directories("/home/buzz/boost_1_80_0")
link_directories("/home/buzz/boost_1_80_0/build/lib")
add_library(cshare_data_boost MODULE cshare_data_pyinterface/cshare_data_boost.cpp)
target_link_libraries(cshare_data_boost python3.8)
target_link_libraries(cshare_data_boost boost_python38)
target_link_libraries(cshare_data_boost cshare_data)
```

### Python - Calling C wrappers

Just for the purpose of demonstration, I've written 3 different processes that share the same `int_val` (handled by the above `MyProcess`) and call the C function to print the value of this variable. Note that, though the lines of code are the same, the address must be withdrawn at each process call since `multiprocessing.sharedctypes` wraps IPC synchronizing architecture for `int_val` under the hood, meaning that each actual `int_val` lives in the proper process.

```
my_proc = MyProcess()
my_proc.start()

l = []


class FromWhere(IntEnum):
    ctype = 0
    python_c_extension = 1
    boost_python = 2

def from_ctype_import_dll(int_val: RawValue):
    import ctypes
    reference = st.ctypes.byref(my_proc.int_val)
    mylib=ctypes.CDLL("clibs/cshare_data.so")
    mylib.cshare_data.argtypes=[ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_char]
    mylib.cshare_data(reference, FromWhere.ctype.value)


def from_python_c_extension(int_val: RawValue):
    from clibs import cshare_data_pyext
    address = st.ctypes.addressof(int_val)
    cshare_data_pyext.cshare_data(address)

def from_boost_python(int_val: RawValue):
    from clibs import cshare_data_boost
    address = st.ctypes.addressof(int_val)
    cshare_data_boost.cshare_data(address)

ps: List[Process] = []

ps.append(Process(target=from_ctype_import_dll, args=(my_proc.int_val,)))
ps.append(Process(target=from_python_c_extension, args=(my_proc.int_val,)))
ps.append(Process(target=from_boost_python, args=(my_proc.int_val,)))

for p in ps:
    p.start()

for p in ps:
    p.join()
```

The result achieved:

```
Value in Python Process:  0
C code read from cTypes CDLL a value of: 1
C code read from Python C Extension a value of: 1
C code read from Boost::Python a value of: 1
Value in Python Process:  1
C code read from cTypes CDLL a value of: 2
C code read from Boost::Python a value of: 2
C code read from Python C Extension a value of: 2
Value in Python Process:  2
C code read from cTypes CDLL a value of: 3
C code read from Boost::Python a value of: 3
C code read from Python C Extension a value of: 3
C code read from cTypes CDLL a value of: 3
Value in Python Process:  3
C code read from Boost::Python a value of: 4
C code read from Python C Extension a value of: 4
C code read from cTypes CDLL a value of: 4
Value in Python Process:  4
C code read from Boost::Python a value of: 5
C code read from Python C Extension a value of: 5
C code read from cTypes CDLL a value of: 5
Value in Python Process:  5
C code read from Boost::Python a value of: 6
C code read from Python C Extension a value of: 6
C code read from cTypes CDLL a value of: 6
Value in Python Process:  6
C code read from Python C Extension a value of: 7
C code read from Boost::Python a value of: 7
C code read from cTypes CDLL a value of: 7
Value in Python Process:  7
C code read from Python C Extension a value of: 8
C code read from Boost::Python a value of: 8
C code read from cTypes CDLL a value of: 8
Value in Python Process:  8
C code read from Python C Extension a value of: 9
C code read from Boost::Python a value of: 9
C code read from cTypes CDLL a value of: 9
Value in Python Process:  9
C code read from Python C Extension a value of: 10
C code read from Boost::Python a value of: 10
```